# SuspendThread WOW64 suspending in kernel code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wow64

***UPDATE***: Microsoft have yet to fix it in Windows 8.1.

***EDIT***: This turned out to be a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/1558e9ca-8180-4633-a349-534e8d51cf3a) in WOW64 - GetThreadContext() may return stale contents when the thread is suspended in long mode ring-3 (user mode). I've suggested to Microsoft to use ring-2 to perform the translation. SuspendThread would then only suspend thread in ring-3 (as it does now - no changes necessary), and a crash/fault/exploit in ring-2 won't affect the kernel - it'd only affect ring-2 and ring-3.

Such changes would necessitate the change of a few WinAPI functions such as Wow64Get/SetThreadContext etc. This would break apps relying on undocumented features but that's to be expected. Granted, translation would be slower as it takes a few CPU cycles to transition from ring-3 to ring-2 (depending on the CPU family) but I'd think that the role of the OS is first and foremost to ensure correct operation. Translation already adds overhead to apps running under WOW64, so that's to be expected too.

I do hope that Microsoft would fix this issue - otherwise debuggers / Mono apps / Boehm GC / apps that rely on GetThreadContext() under WOW64 would not work (for starters, I've seen debuggers show stale stack trace).

***EDIT2***: Bad news. From my conversation with Alexey from MSFT ([here](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/11/wow64-bug-getthreadcontext-may-return.html)) it looks as though it may not get fixed at all in fear that the fix would break apps that rely on undocumented features.

---

**Original question**

- Some people seem to be confused about the following. I initially thought it was due to SuspendThread suspending a thread while in kernel-mode code. It wasn't. The following was merely my initial suspicion which turned out to have nothing to do with the actual root cause -- which was the stale contents returned by `GetThreadContext()`.

From MSDN:

`Suspending a thread causes the thread to stop executing user-mode (application) code.`

What I've found however is that my 32-bit app in Windows 7 running under WOW64, Thread A calling SuspendThread on Thread B can pause it while it's running 64-bit code (which I would expect is *not* user-mode code). EIP shows the suspended thread stopped at

```
wow64cpu!X86SwitchTo64BitMode:
00000000`759c31b0 ea27369c753300  jmp     0033:759C3627
```

with its ESP having changed (I know this because, while the ESP is pointing to the same page as that thread's stack, it's got a much higher address than the current stack pointer). If I put a breakpoint at the instruction which the above returns to, and then get the thread to resume, I found that the ESP changes back to the value before the X86SwitchTo64BitMode call (which is the correct stack pointer). I also found that when single stepping into the same function, I can never get that higher address ESP value at any point of the single step. In fact, when single stepping, ESP value never changes before and after the X86SwitchTo64BitMode call.

Also, I did make sure SuspendThread succeed by checking against (DWORD)-1.

All of these leads me to believe that the thread is suspended in kernel-mode code.

What could be causing the OS to suspend a thread while it's running non-user-mode code? How do I prevent that? This is basically preventing me from getting the actual current stack pointer of Thread B. Note that when the app runs outside of WOW64 (on native x86 OS), no such problem exists.

Comment: While you may be right about having a bug, it's just not true that 64-bit code in a 32-bit process is only in kernel mode.  There's a 64-bit shim that properly sets up the syscall using 64-bit pointers.  That shim isn't "user code", but it is "user-mode code".

Comment: Also, you are completely misinterpreting the documentation statement "Suspending a thread causes the thread to stop executing user-mode (application) code."  You're reading it as if it contained the word *only*.  It does not.  That statement makes no claims at all about the effect on kernel-mode code.  Some kernel calls may be suspended, others may not.

Comment: @BenVoigt You should read the whole post including the updates before commenting. I left the original text in my question as a preface to the actual problem. Suspending in kernel-mode code was never the problem (which I initially thought it was when I started hunting down this bug). The problem with SO is that the questions and answers aren't formatted in a chronological order -- so people who read it much later aren't privy to the actual development that happened earlier on.

Comment: I'm trying to save future readers from your faulty conclusions.  Although you may have corrected them during troubleshooting, you've still left them here in the question.  And yes, I read your edits, and they don't correct your misstatements, they just point to a more insidious source of your trouble.

Comment: For example, your newest edit.  "It wasn't."  Does that mean "SuspendThread *did* suspend kernel code, and that wasn't the problem" or "SuspendThread didn't suspend kernel code" or "I don't know if SuspendThread suspended kernel code and no longer care, because the problem is elsewhere"

Comment: Problem is elsewhere. If you feel what I've written isn't clear, feel free to correct it.

Comment: @Zach Saw: I'm having much the same problem, and have followed all your various posts.  I agree that for a clean abstraction, SuspendThread's implementation seems seriously broken.  For me, all I care about is that I can get SuspendThread to suspend the thread *somewhere* in user code. I'm not happy but can live calling it multiple times, if I can figure out that a particular call didn't succeed cleanly.  You(?) mention something called CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST and hint that it will tell that a retreived context is bogus (or, is Kernal state/stale/....).  Where is usage of this documented?

Comment: @ZachSaw: (2nd comment as a kind of ping... you're apparantly online frequently.  *Really* interested in CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST docs and usage).

Comment: @ZachSaw: I don't know if this helps, but if the PC from GetContext is accurate, and you can tell it is not in your code, you might actually try single-stepping that thread until it *is* in your code, and then your ESP would be right. (I've considered this but I don't need to get the user context *at this instant* right so I'm not quite as desperate as you).

Comment: @ZachSaw: Apparantly a Win32 app can call Wow64GetThreadContext; maybe that has the CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST data, which appears to tell you if you thread is in your space, or the system space.  It will take me awhile to experiment with this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @IraBaxter: `CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST` is only available on Win8. Prior OSes are still broken. On Win8, using that flag will tell you if your GetContext values are accurate. Also, EIP is no exception when the values are inaccurate / stale. The WOW64 emulator simply returns the last known values (clearly a bug as this behavior wasn't / still isn't documented anywhere).

Comment: @ZachSaw:  OK, so CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST only works with Win8.  Is it implemented using the Win32 GetThreadContext API, or do you have to do something else?

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, call the Win32 GetThreadContext with that flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed that this is an OS issue returning stale contents when GetThreadContext is called under WOW64.

[More info here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/1558e9ca-8180-4633-a349-534e8d51cf3a/?prof=required).

Thanks to everyone who attempted to answer this question. I'm working with MS to resolve this.

Comment: So.. does this affect the Visual Studio debugger when debugging wow64 apps?

Answer (score 1):

See this explanation : [GetThreadContext in Wow64](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=129)

This article explains, that the transition between x86 and amd64 modes is done in user-mode.

Comment: Does this mean that I could also transition from x86 to x64 in my user-mode code?

Comment: How would I be able to get the current stack pointer of Thread B then?

Comment: @1) Yeah, should be possible. But could have 'interesting' effects. @2) Either you build a 64bit executable, or you rethink your design, i don't think you can efficiently use a 64bit stack pointer in a 32bit executable to do anything of value.

Comment: I don't want the 64-bit stack pointer - I want the 32bit one. The app works perfectly fine on 32-bit OSes. It's only when it's being run under WOW64 that it breaks. WOW64 is supposed to emulate 32-bit Windows but it's not doing a very good job of it!

Comment: I understand more from the article now. It says WOW64 thread context is stored and accessible in user-mode - that's fair enough. In fact, that's why this is even more evidence that my problem is a bug in WOW64. I could see that the reason a WOW64 thread context is separate from the 64-bit context is because MS don't want any of the 64-bit code to clobber the WOW64 context. The fact that it does means that it isn't properly emulating Win32.

Comment: After we established, that we are in user mode. Do you get the ESP of the translate call, or do you get an 'invalid' value in the ESP? Are you using GetThreadContext, or some deviation?

Comment: It's a stale thread context contents - Skywing has acknowledge this problem in WOW64. More info here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/1558e9ca-8180-4633-a349-534e8d51cf3a/?prof=required

Answer (score 0):

What does your thread do in user-mode? It seems like it's already in kernel-mode when you call `SuspendThread`. Is it possible that it's executing a system function in the moment you suspend it?

> What could be causing the OS to suspend a thread while it's running non-user-mode code?

Many system or library calls may result in switch to the kernel-mode. And because the Windows Kernel is designed to be reentrant in most cases, switching from one thread to another while the first one is in kernel-mode is pretty normal.

> How do I prevent that?

Just an idea: Create a thread that is just executing an empty loop (e.g. `for(;;);`) and suspend that thread. This one should not be suspended in kernel-mode.

---

Also, why is it important to you that the ESP registers etc. are correct? I hope you are writing some kind of debugger or something related, because that's what `SuspendThread` is for.

Comment: Yes, it's something related to debugger. From my understanding (and according to MSDN), SuspendThread is meant to suspend only if it's running user-mode code. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: I'm not questioning if SuspendThread could suspend a thread while it's running user-mode code - that's the expected behavior. So suspending your empty loop is really not proving anything.

Comment: And yes, thread A is running SetEvent when thread B suspended it. Like I said, it's not meant to suspend the thread while it's running 64-bit code though. It's basically clobbered by ESP by doing so and I have no way of getting the true current stack pointer.

Comment: If A is running SetEvent when B suspends it, then the X86SwitchTo64BitMode ESP **is** the *true current stack pointer*. There is no other ESP that might be more true or something. The only *more true* stack pointer is in the 64bit RSP.

Comment: Yeah if that's the case, it would've been the expected behavior and my app would've continued to work as it has in native x86 OS. Obviously, that's *NOT* the case - otherwise I wouldn't have even asked the question to begin with ;) I'm get ESP of which was the previous call out to long mode code - eons ago up the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, when a thread isn't running at all, it's running neither kernel-mode code nor user-mode code. So your observations do not contradict the statement.

Beisdes, you shouldn't be messing with this. It would be an OS bug if you (in user mode) could control whether kernel mode code was executed.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question. I need SuspendThread to "stop executing user-mode (application) code" while not suspending while it's running kernel mode code. My understanding is that SuspendThread should not suspend the thread when it's running kernel mode code (return (DWORD)-1). Are you saying this is incorrect?

Comment: And what do you mean by thread isn't running at all? I wasn't calling SuspendThread on a suspended thread - I was calling it on a running thread.

Comment: @Zach Saw: Yes, you have misunderstood. You may call SuspendThread() at any moment, especially since you usually call it from another thread and have no idea whether the target thread is executing kernel code. With "when a thread isn't running at all", I mean the state after `SuspendThread` has completely stopped a thread - no more application code is running, but also no kernel mode code.

Comment: Wow, is that how you interpret "Suspending a thread causes the thread to stop executing user-mode (application) code." MAte, you're quite... unique. ;)

Comment: Don't think so, actually. Heck, just take the most trivial of cases, a thread that's reading a file. It seems you think you can't suspend such a thread because `ReadFile` (at least some of the time) is executing kernel-mode code.

Comment: I'm not saying it is so, I'm saying MSDN said so. Yes, there are situations where you'd find that a thread is suspended in kernel mode (which contradicts MSDN) but only if it's outside of critical region. If a thread is not in user mode, it is in kernel mode - your reply says a CPU can be in neither ring-0 nor ring-3. Perhaps you meant ring-1 and 2? They're not used in Windows ATM.

Comment: Proves my point: you can _call_ SuspendThread even if that thread has a critical kernel section locked, it just means that the thread is not immediately suspended when you make the call.

Comment: How is that proof to what you've given as the answer??? And again with your reply, "no more application code is running, but also no kernel mode code".

Comment: @ZachSaw: MSDN says nothing at all about the effect of `SuspendThread` on kernel-mode code.  So if you find that `SuspendThread` has suspended it in kernel mode, there is no contradiction.

Comment: @BenVoigt No contradiction of MSDN sure -- but are you defending this -- "it's running neither kernel-mode code nor user-mode code"???

Comment: @Zach: I see what MSalters is saying, but I don't think that statement is a useful answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  I don't mind SuspendThread freezing a thread in kernal mode; after all, I'm *suspending* it.   I just want to know if I can inspect its *user* state.  GetThreadContext doesn't seem to tell you that the thread is in kernal mode or not; how do I find out? For my application, (probably not for Zach's), I'm perfectly happy to resume the  thread and stop it again if this occurs (ick yuk polling) but I believe that would be rare and therefore workable.

Comment: @Ira: On second thought, even if the thread gets suspending in the middle of an interruptible syscall, `GetThreadContext` and especially `SetThreadContext` had better not work on the kernel-mode context, since that could lead to arbitrary code execution in kernel context.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, one would not SetThreadContext to work on a kernal-mode context.  Thats a problem for MS, but doesn't affect my question.  All I want to know is when I call GetThreadContext, if the result I get is valid ("is for user code") or not.  If not for user code, I have no intereest in actually inspecting the state; I'll just restart the thread, suspend again, and ask for context again.  Is there any way to know if the results of GetThreadContext are for "user mode"?  If there is no way to know, then GetThreadContext seems completely useless. ...

Comment: ... (useless).   Not quite: with enough effort, my program can know that a thread is executing in user mode.   Just put a flag around every system call, which I have done, so I in fact have the "not in user mode signal".   Arg, *not quite*.  It turns out that traps (esp. division by zero) go into system mode, and I have no flag wrapped around "division by zero", so there's a hole in my scheme.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I believe that inspecting a thread context from kernel mode would reveal that it is from kernel mode.  However, Zach's description of the bug, apparently corroborated by some MS engineers, is that there's some machinery to give a user-mode thread context when the thread is in kernel mode, and that has a race condition allowing it to return stale information.  On his post in the MS forums, Zach indicated he had automated detection of the problem wired to a breakpoint.

Comment: @IraBaxter: OTOH, even an automated detection with some false negatives would be useful for proving that a problem exists.