# Embedded mono crashes with GetThreadContext failed (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, mono, embedded-language

I'm using mono-2.11.4 on Windows 7 in 32 bit and 64 bit for embedding into my C++ application. Since updating from an rather old 2.6.4 mono I'm getting an error "GetThreadContext failed" from the GC every now and then (there seems to be no pattern).
The same error occurs with mono-3.0.1 both for 32 bit and 64 bit.

Any ideas what causes this and how to get back to stable operation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144600/suspendthread-wow64-suspending-in-kernel-code for a probable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Kaspersky antivirus.

Comment: There's no virus scanner involved or even installed here.